# Static Block And Object Block Access In java

Tags: java, jvm

I read about object block that I mention below:

```
class Check {

    static {
        System.out.println("hello from Static");
    }
    //object block
    {
        System.out.println("This is my object block");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
}
```

This is the output of program

```
Hello from Static
```

But when I make the object of class then object block is execute. **I can't understand how this process is done by jvm.** Is there any role of garbage collector?

```
class Check {

    static {
        System.out.println("hello from Static");
    }
    //object block

    {
        System.out.println("This is my object block");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("hello from main");
        Check obj = new check();
    }
}
```

this is the Output:

```
hello from Static
hello from main
This is my object block
```

Answer (score 6):

The `static` blocks are executed whenever a classloader loads the class (this is most commonly done once per JVM instance, but I suppose you could create some *very* weird situation where you had multiple classloaders that all load the class; that's not a very beginner-level situation, though). The instance initializer blocks are executed every time you create an instance of that class (or one of its subclasses). Your program requires that:

1. The class is loaded by the JVM; this triggers the static initializer block (`hello from Static`).
2. The `main` static method is executed

   1. A `println` is executed (`hello from main`).
   2. You create an instance of `Check`. This triggers the instance initializer, leading to `This is my object block`.

The GC doesn't have anything to do with the behavior you're asking about, FTR.

Comment: Suppose sir
in class i have
1.static varable
2.Static block
3.static method
4.main method
5.simple method
6.simple variable
7.constructor

**in which manner they are executed.**

Comment: @PradeepBhati you should probably go read the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) if you need that level of detail. If you do, it's probably for some sort of test, and you'll want the most official datasource. If you're running into this sort of thing in the real world, you're probably better off trying to simplify your logic. If it takes you a long time to reason about it as your write it, that's a good sign it will take you a long time to figure it out again in 6 months when you're doing maintenance and come across it again after you've forgotten all the context.

Comment: actually i learn java from **herbert schildt ** in that book there is no more information mention about static that i learn here thank you sir for your guidence.

Comment: @PradeepBhati Generally speaking, static initializers and class initializers are run—in the order in which they appear in the text of the file—whenever the class is loaded, which must happen before you can reference that class, for example: accessing a class member, either a variable or a method. That means that those will always have executed once before you can instantiate the class. When you instantiate a class, instance initializers and instance variable initializers are executed first, then whichever constructor you used to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Java Language Specification, the static blocks will be executed when the class is loaded and initialized by the classloader. As for the initialization blocks, they will be executed when the class is instantiated.

Please, refer to sections [Static Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.7) and [Instance Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.6) in the Java Language Specification (1.6)

Answer (score 1):

The order of events

- The class is initialized, prints `hello from Static`
- The main method is called, prints `hello from main`
- The object is constructed, prints `This is my object block`

Answer (score 0):

The static block is executed whenever the class is loaded into the JVM. 
Whereas the object block or constructor block will be run when you create an instance of said object.

This article described the differences very well:
http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php